# How to get the current view count of all videos on a channel from the youtube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

While the subscription count in

```
www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics
```

seems to be updated instantly, the views update around daily.

A workaround that I found was to list all videos in the "uploaded" playlist with

```
www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails
```

and iterate through them, calling

```
www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics
```

for each. This seems to get the most accurate results, though it requires more than 3 credits for every uploaded video, thus using my quota up relatively fast.

Is there a faster way around the problem?
I would like to implement it on an ESP8266 so it would be preferable not to require a lot of storage or processing power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the view count by getting the [`liveStreamingDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails), the `liveStreamingDetails` object contains metadata about a live video broadcast. The object will only be present in a video resource if the video is an upcoming, live, or completed live broadcast. Then, under this, you will get the [`concurrentViewers`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers). It will show the number of viewers currently watching the broadcast. The property and its value will be present if the broadcast has current viewers and the broadcast owner has not hidden the viewcount for the video

**EDIT**

Specific to your use case, I believe a 2-part API would help with your inquiry.

I'm thinking of you calling a `search` query to retrieve all videos of the channel. The [Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search) resource will have the `id.videoId` that you'll concatenate as part of the [`list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call. This will give you the `statistics.viewCount` of each video, which you'll need to add up to get the total channel view count.

Hopefully this helps with your inquiry.

Happy coding!

Comment: I am not asking for how to get the number of views of a live broadcast, but rather how to get the current total number of views of all videos on a selected channel.

Comment: Changed the title to reflect it better.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, hopefully its sufficient with what you'll need.

Comment: "A call to this method has a quota cost of 1 unit in addition to the costs of the specified resource parts."
So the total cost would be 3 (to list the videos from playlist) + 3 (to get the statistics from IDs) to get each 50 videos, right? And all future calls could use cached video IDs?

Comment: It will only cost you 3 points for the `Videos:list` call since you'll only need the `statistics` part (`search` call doesn't indicate if there's quota cost, which I'm presuming there isn't any). However, future calls would likely still incur quota cost.

Comment: The search page indicates "Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the channelId parameter and sets the type parameter value to video", so I think using playlistItems with the "uploaded" playlist is still the way to go. The cost of Videos:list doesn't depend on the number of videos included, correct?

Comment: Yes, it won't depend on the number of videos, regardless of how many comma-separated `videoid` is on the the `id` parameter, it will still cost you about 3 quota points (depending on the `part`s you'll need.